# How can I override "ribbonServerListFilter"

Tags: spring-cloud

I want to be able to override the default Spring Cloud 'ribbonServerListFilter' implementation. I have read the docs but I always get an error regarding a bean it cannot find (IClientConfig).

So I have a simple class like:

```
@Configuration
public class FooConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ServerListFilter<Server> ribbonServerListFilter(IClientConfig config) {
        MyListFilter filter = new MyListFilter();
        filter.initWithNiwsConfig(config);
        return filter;
    }

}
```

and:

```
@Configuration
@RibbonClient(name = "foo", configuration = FooConfiguration.class)
public class TestConfiguration {
}
```

But then at runtime I get:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: \
Error creating bean with name 'ribbonServerListFilter' defined in class path \
resource [FooConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through \
constructor argument with index 0 of type \
[com.netflix.client.config.IClientConfig]: : No qualifying bean of type \
[com.netflix.client.config.IClientConfig] found for dependency
```

So what am I doing wrong?

This is with Spring Boot 1.3.1.RELEASE.

Thanks in advance.

Henry

UPDATE:

Adding full source after Dave's comments.

```
package com.domain1;
...
@Configuration
public class FooConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ServerListFilter<Server> ribbonServerListFilter(IClientConfig config) {
        System.out.println("My ribbonServerListFilter will be used");
        MyListFilter filter = new MyListFilter();
        filter.initWithNiwsConfig(config);
        return filter;
    }
}

package com.domain1;
...
public class MyListFilter extends ZonePreferenceServerListFilter {
    @Override
    public List<Server> getFilteredListOfServers(List<Server> servers) {
        System.out.println("This is my version");
        return super.getFilteredListOfServers(servers);
    }
}
```

And the main application in a different package:

```
package com.domain2;
...
@Configuration
@RibbonClient(name = "foo", configuration = FooConfiguration.class)
public class TestConfiguration {
}

package com.domain2;
...
@Component
@Configuration
public class Runner implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;
    @Autowired
    private LoadBalancerClient loadBalancer;
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("all");
        for (ServiceInstance s : discoveryClient.getInstances("service")) {
            System.out.println(s.getHost() + ":" + s.getPort());
        }
        System.out.println("from lb");
        ServiceInstance instance = loadBalancer.choose("service");
        System.out.println(instance.getHost() + ":" + instance.getPort());
    }
}

package com.domain2;
...
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

So in the second test when calling 'loadBalancer.choose' I expected my code to be called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make sure your `FooConfiguration` is not component scanned. Put it in a separate package not under the main application, or don't use `@ComponentScan`.

Comment: So put FooConfiguration under com.domain1 but keep TestConfiguration under com.domain2 (like my main())? I tried that but then the override never seemed to register and the default (ZonePreferenceServerListFilter) was still executed.

Comment: What's the new behavior (logs errors)? Maybe a project that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Spencer, please see the code above. I updated it with my test app. No runtime errors with that. But it never calls my code.

Comment: See https://github.com/radubutnaru/spring-ribbon-config-issue for a working example. When I model my application after that, it works as expected. The problem was that I called the config ("foo") something else than the service I was trying to load-balance ("service"). Calling them the same resolved the problem. Thanks for your help!